# TypeError: range indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two nested for loops in my code but one works and not the other, they are also identical and its doing my head in

this code works

````
def nearest(furthestpoints,lastpoints,lastIDs,currentpoints,img,threshold = 30):
    currentIDs = np.empty(0,dtype = float)
    normList = np.empty(0,dtype = float)

    for i in range(0,len(currentpoints)):
        for a in range(0,len(lastpoints)):
            normList = np.append(normList,np.linalg.norm(currentpoints[i,:] - lastpoints[a,:]))```
````

but this code produces the error

```
File "/home/oliver/tracker.py", line 22, in getLostPoints
    normList = np.append(normList,np.linalg.norm(current[i,:] - last[a,:]))
TypeError: range indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

```
def getLostPoints(last,lastIDs,current,threshold = 50):

    normList = np.empty(0,dtype = float)
    goodIDs = np.empty(0,dtype = int)
    lostPoints = np.empty((2,0),dtype = float)

    for i in range(0,len(last)):
        for a in range(0,len(current)):
            normList = np.append(normList,np.linalg.norm(current[i,:] - last[a,:]))

        if min(normList) < threshold:
            indexMin = np.argmin(normList)
            goodIDs = np.append(goodIDs,lastIDs[indexMin])
        normList = np.empty(0,dtype = float)
```

these are just the loops there is more to this code

the input arrays are of shape `(n,2)`
where `n` is the number of points

Comment: Your slices are: current[i,:] - last[a,:]. you meant them to be: current[i:] - last[a:] without the commas.

Comment: this doesnt work as the arrays im trying to index are of shape (5,2) what you suggest produces a broadcast error ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (5,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem it was a simple error when i call the code in the main loop
it now works fine thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough of a reputation to comment, so I have to post this as an answer.

First, you have:

```
    for i in range(0,len(current)):
        for a in range(0,len(current)):
```

Did you mean:

```
    for i in range(0,len(current)):
        for a in range(0,len(last)):
```

This would follow the same pattern as your method that works.

Have you tried printing `i` and `a` in your second method just as a sanity check as well as printing the characteristics of your inputs (shape, etc.)? It's not the most eloquent way to debug, but printing values just to make sure they are what you expect can be insightful.

Comment: oops yea sorry i did mean that it doesnt change the error though ill change the post ive also done all the debugging things i just didnt want to put it in the code to make it look messy but i and a are both of <type int>